# How can I add more than one S3 folder in GreatExpectations as my Data Asset?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, great-expectations

I am attempting to create a Data Asset using the GreatExpectations library to point to all the files in subfolders under a parent folder. Here is a sample code snippet:

```py
asset_name = "iceberg_asset" 
s3_prefix = "folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/" 
batching_regex = r"subfolder_a\/file\.parquet" 

data_asset = datasource.add_parquet_asset(name=asset_name, batching_regex=batching_regex, s3_prefix=s3_prefix)
```

The batching_regex is supposed to capture all files with a specific full path, which includes the parent folder and file name. However, the current code is not working and returning an error message "file not found." I have confirmed that the regex is working fine.

Currently, only the regexp that matches the files under the s3_prefix is working. Does anyone have any suggestions to get this working for folders and files that match the regexp?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Add `s3_recursive_file_discovery=True`-parameter to the asset definition.

**Longer version**

If I understood correctly, you would like GX to recursively find all of the files in the different sub-folders.

This is done be setting `s3_recursive_file_discovery` parameter to `True`. This tells GX to recursively find files from all of the sub-folders inside the parent folder.

This would look like:

```
asset_name = "iceberg_asset" 
s3_prefix = "folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/" 
batching_regex = r"subfolder_a\/file\.parquet" 

data_asset = datasource.add_parquet_asset(
    name=asset_name,
    batching_regex=batching_regex,
    s3_prefix=s3_prefix,
    s3_recursive_file_discovery=True,
)
```

This makes GX to recursively search **all** of the sub-folders inside the `s3_prefix`-folder. GX won't limit checking the files to the regex you provided. GX will find all of the paths in that folder and then drop the paths that don't match the regex pattern.

**NOTE!** Make sure to evaluate the impact this has on your costs and resources. GX will download all of the matching files from the sub-folders when i.e. running a Data Assistant.

Also, it's good to note that GX will currently (version 0.17.5) validate only the last file of a data asset. GX will use all of the files when i.e. running the Data Assistant.

And finally, by default GX will find 1000 paths. You can increase/decrese this by adding `s3_max_keys`-parameter to the Data Asset.